# How to remove backslashes in ruby strings

Tags: ruby

In ruby, I am trying to convert

```
'\"\"'
```

to

```
'""'
```

In short, what's the cleanest way to remove the backslashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `gsub` method on any string to remove unwanted characters.

```
some_string.gsub('\\"', '"')
```

Comment: You should replace `String` with `string` or somesuch, lest it be confused with the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another:

```
'\"\"'.delete("\\") # => "\"\""
```

Comment: i think before and after delete has no different string, sorry i did not get your answer.

Comment: @AhmadLeoYudanto, `'\"\"' ==  "\"\"" #=> false`. `'\"\"'.size #=> 4` (the characters \, ", \ and ", whereas `"\"\"".size #=> 2` (""). The backslash character is written `'\\'` or `"\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-tr)

```
s = '\"\"'
s.tr('\\', '') # => "\"\""
```